# XSD regular expression restriction on xsd:string

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xml-validation

What would be the regular expression if I want a sequence of integers separated with at least one blank?

Something like "123 098".

Comment: database 235,right?lol

Comment: Why do you want a regular expression for this? Why not define the type as `xs:list itemType='xs:integer'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to use a regular expression for two sequences of digits separated by at least one whitespace character:

```
<xs:simpleType name="twoSequencesOfDigitsType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="\d+\s+\d+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```